# Unflattening list returns unexpected Error in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have read all the posts about unflattening lists on Stackoverflow but I can't find a solution to my problem.

I have two lists and I want to add one element from list2 to every element in list1.

```
l1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
l2 = [5, 7]
```

and the result I am after is

```
[[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 6]]
```

I have tried this code

```
for i in range(len(l2)):
    l1[i].extend(l2[i])

print(l1)
```

but returns an Error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

When every element of l2 is a list by itself e.g. `l2 = [[5],[7]]` 
my code works fine. Why is that? And how do I adjust my code to work when l2 is in this format `l2 = [5, 7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip()` to iterate over two or more things in parallel. Using `range()` to make indexes when you don't need them is unpythonic.

```
xss = [[1,2],[3,4]]
ys = [5,7]

for xs, y in zip(xss, ys):
    xs.append(y)

print(xss)
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list1.extend(list2)` is to create `list1+list2`. But you are not providing `list2`, instead, it is just an element. The right function to do that is `list1.append(element2)`, which is same as `list1+[element2]`

Answer (score -1):

```
l1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
l2 = [5, 7]
for i in range(len(l2)):
l1[i].append(l2[i]);

print(l1)
```

[[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 7]]

```
Extend is for objects.
Append is what you need here.
```

Comment: Probably because you provided code with no explanation as to what it means, how it works or how it answers the question. That is not what SO is about. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Your "answer" is up for deletion by Review.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23050182)

Comment: Very minimal .extend to .append fixing. Since extend uses objects and append is what he wanted here.